# How to limit the generation of random alpha number to 12?

Tags: java, android

I have been using this code to help me generate a random number of aplphabet and numbers. However, it generated 26 alpha,numerical number for me. How should i reduce it to 12 alpha numeric? Which is from "vc24maepo1g3at4ucsv4t9radm" to "553b4f6362f6c".

```
 public final class SessionIdentifierGenerator {
    private SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

    public String nextSessionId() {
        return new BigInteger(130, random).toString(32);
    }
}
```

Comment: if the output is string you can try `.substring(0, 12)`;

Comment: where should .substring(0, 12) be place? i try to substitude with .toString but it cant be used

Comment: append after .toString().substring(0, 12)

Comment: try `return new BigInteger(130, random).toString(32).substring(0, 12);`

Comment: @CheongCharlene uyse subString(0,12) after toString(32), you will get 12 as a result.

Answer (score 1):

The problem of the substring method is, that it will fail unexpectedly.

Why? The javadoc of [BigInteger(int numBits, Random rnd)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger-int-java.util.Random-)
says

> Constructs a randomly generated BigInteger, uniformly distributed over the range 0 to (2numBits - 1), inclusive.

Which means the `BigInteger` could be one. The `toString(32)` would generate the string `1`. From this string the `substring(0, 12)`
would fail with a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

The requirement is `to get a string representation of a randomly generated number in radix 32 with twelf digits`.

Whe can do some maths.

- a digit of base 32 can be represented with five bits (the value 0-31)
- for a number of base 32 with twelf digits we need as minimum `11*5 bit + 1` bits (100000000000 in radix 32)
- so we need to find a random number which is in the range `11*5 bit + 1` and `12 * 5 bit`

The smallest twelf digit number in radix 32 as hex is `0x80000000000000` and the biggest is `0xfffffffffffffff`.

So the code for this computation would be (as verbose)

```
Random random = new Random();
// get a random value
long nextLong = random.nextLong();
// to ensure the value is in the expected range we
// limit the value to not exceed the maximum "& 0xfffffffffffffffL"
// set the highest bit "| 0x800000000000000L"
// convert the value to a string representation in radix 32
String value=Long.toString(nextLong & 0xfffffffffffffffL | 0x800000000000000L, 32);
```

For better understanding some visual explanation. ;-)

```
Long minTwelfDigitRadix32 = Long.valueOf("100000000000", 32);
Long maxTwelfDigitRadix32 = Long.valueOf("vvvvvvvvvvvv", 32);

System.out.printf("[%60s]%n", Long.toBinaryString(minTwelfDigitRadix32));
System.out.printf("[%60s]%n", Long.toBinaryString(maxTwelfDigitRadix32));

System.out.printf("[%15s]%n", Long.toHexString(minTwelfDigitRadix32));
System.out.printf("[%15s]%n", Long.toHexString(maxTwelfDigitRadix32));
```

**output**

```
[    10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000]
[111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111]
[ 80000000000000]
[fffffffffffffff]
```

PS: Setting always the highest bit will reduce the number of random values. If this is not desired we could first check if the 
random number is greater or equal to the minimum number `100000000000` (radix 32) and set a random bit of the highest digit.

Using the java 8 Stream API a soulution would be

```
String value = IntStream.range(1, 13)
        .map((int o) -> o == 1 ? random.nextInt(31) + 1 : random.nextInt(32))
        .boxed()
        .map(o -> Integer.toString(o, 32))
        .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

- generate an ordered `int` stream with the values 1 to 13
- for each value in the stream we compute a random value, for the first position (the highest digit we need to ensure that it's value is in the range from 1 to 31, see above), for all other we compute a value in the range from 0 to 31)
- we need to convert the primitve `int` into `Integers`
- map each random value to a string representation using radix 32
- join all strings

PPS: If this is to be used for a huge number of values, the first way might perform better. Have not done some exhaustive test.